# Guidelines for designing a robust file format writer?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, file-format, writer

Suppose you want to write a .WAV file format writer like so:

```
using var stream = File.OpenRead("test.wav");
using var writer = new WavWriter(stream, ... /* .WAV format parameters */);

// write the file

// writer.Dispose() does a few things:
// - writes user-added chunks
// - updates the file header (chunk size) so the file is valid
```

There is a concpetual problem in doing so:

- the user can change the stream position and therefore screw the writing process

You may suggest the following:

- the writer should own the stream, this would work if writing to a file, but not to a stream
- own its own memory stream so it can write to streams too, okay but memory concerns

I guess you get the point...

To me, the only viable thing would be to document that aspect but I may have missed something, hence the question.

**Question:**

How to make a file format writer be able to write to a stream yet defend yourself about possible changes to its position?

Comment: Why do you need to defend against a user intentionally sabotaging their own work?  If they are passing a stream to a WavWriter it should be obvious that they should not do anything with the stream themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to keep an internal position field in the `WavWriter`. Each time you do some operation you can check that this matches the position in the backing stream and throw an exception if it does not. Update this value at the end of each write operation.

Ideally you should also handle streams that does not support seeking, but it does not sound like your design would permit that anyway. It might be a good idea to check `CanSeek` in the constructor and throw if seek is not supported. It is in general a good idea to validate any arguments before usage.

Comment: Good ideas.  Check that seek is available at startup and throw a "stream must support seek" exception, check that the position matches before each update.

Comment: I'm already checking for the seeking aspect. Now your idea was rather easy to implement but the more I think about it, the more I think @DaveS is right. Why bother with someone who wants to get in trouble ? Someone can write something, then set position back and that would be an invisible change. If only there were callbacks for stream methods that'd be doable but there aren't any in .NET. I think some **undefined** in the docs is just the way to go, i.e. the best APIs are the simplest ones.

Comment: @aybe I totally agree with Dave S on that point. This was written on the assumption that you *do* want some kind of extra check. The important thing is to try checking for the mistakes users are most likely to make.

Comment: That's right, thanks!